# Check if item from one object exists in another (using underscore)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I am trying to compare 2 objets using underscore, specifically I am trying to compare the key/values of "`id`" (because other things inside will change). I basically want to just check if object A has an item that object B does not have, remove it from object A. Here is my attempt at it :

```
for(var c=0;c<$scope.types.length;c++){
    var real = _.some($scope.storeTempName, function(it) {
        return it.id == $scope.types[c].typeId; 
    });
    if(real){
    }else{  
        $scope.types.splice(c,1);
    }
}
```

Where `$scope.storeTempName` is object B and `$scope.types` is object A. So if `$scope.types` has something `$scope.storeTempName` does not, remove it (tracking by id and typyId for types).

This first attempt I have works, BUT it only will remove the first one. My guess is it's becasue I'm looping from 0 ++ and the index's are changing when i remove the first one so splice is targetting a false  item. I am not sure though, and could use some help. Thank you for reading!

Comment: Your code would be significantly more readable if you just assigned `$scope.......................types` to something.

Comment: Do you need to use `.splice()` because of angular's data-binding? You could just use a filter otherwise.

Comment: @sacho I Don't need to use splice no, can you filter 2 objects against each other based off 2 different keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use _.filter.

```
$scope.types = _.filter($scope.types, function (type) {
    return _.some($scope.storeTempName, function (it) { return it.id == type.typeId })
})
```